# javascript Как на pixi.js реализовать движение пули

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, математика, pixijs

Добрый вечер, необходимо реализовать игру - "танчики":
1. Вид сверху(координатная плоскость).
2. Пуля должна отскакивать от препятствий.

Как я могу сделать просчет траектории пули? Чтобы был рикошет. Может есть готовые библиотеки?

Можете ли показать готовый пример. У меня есть спрайт "pula". Выходит из точки x = 150 y = 400.

Comment: «угол отражения равен углу падения» https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)#.D0.97.D0.B0.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.BD.D1.8B_.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F._.D0.A4.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D1.83.D0.BB.D1.8B_.D0.A4.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8F 
Проще некуда, не стоит тащить движок из-за такой ерунды.

Comment: Да вот только от вертикальных и горизонтальных, а под углом? Короче сделал через физ движку